# trouble installing the latest version of npm on arch linux

Tags: node.js, archlinux

The version of node on `pacman`, the pacage manager on Arch linux, is not the latest one- but for my programme I need the latest version.

To solve this I tried to download the [source code](https://nodejs.org/en/), downloading the tar ball and then unpacking it and trying to build it.

But when I got inside of the folder, and then looked on [the build instructions on github](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md), the commands to build, i.e.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ [sudo] make install
```

didn't work- so I cloned [the github project](https://github.com/nodejs/node), and followed those instructions above- but all I got was this error:

[image]

how can I install the latest version of node, i.e. node v 4.4.3+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classical `python 2` vs. `python 3` problem.  Arch Linux uses python 3 by default but the `except <exception>, <variable>:` syntax has been dropped in favour of `except <exception> as <variable>:` in python 3.

Full example:

- python 2

  ```
  try: print 'yay'
  except ValueError, e: print e
  ```
- python 3

  ```
  try: print('yay')
  except ValueError as e: print(e)
  ```

The configure script for `npm` is written in python 2.  But, as I said above, Arch uses python 3 as `python`.  You need to change the first line of the [configure script](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/configure) from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

You may need to install `python 2`, since it does not come with Arch by default:

```
pacman -S extra/python2
```

Comment: Or just put symlink to python2 somewhere in /home/<user>/bin/ and add it to PATH before $PATH